# Saving arrays to the hard disk

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a program that uses 2 million arrays of integer values. However, it only uses 200 arrays at a time. 
I have 200 intelligent cars that move over a terrain of 10 000 blocks (divided according to GPS values). Each block has an array of 129x28 that has integer values. When any car moves into a new block, it must retrieve the array which is related to this block then it uses a value in that array. Then it makes a decision based on that value, then it moves on and so on. So the entire system of 200 cars and 10 000 blocks, while each car has its own array distinct values, the total number of arrays is 2 millions. I need to simply retrieve 1 array of each car at a time slot = 200 arrays at a time

the arrays will be created and filled with zeros at the start by the application, then the application will start filling those arrays, finally it will only use them. so I wrote a code to create those arrays in the program.

can't I store the arrays in files on HD and retrieve them when I want?

## Update

Since I had 2 million arrays and I can't store & retrieve 200 arrays in 1-1.9 seconds I down-graded the research to use less environment features and ended up with with using 2 million arrays of size 7 x 28. which used 7 * 28 * 10 000 * 4 (integer) * 200 (cars) bytes
which consumed only 1.6 GB if RAM. Good luck if you're having similar problem, PM if you are in a similar situation and I hope I will be able to help.

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: That's not 2 million arrays, that's 10,000 blocks (tables of size 129x28), which 200 cars look at.  I'm hoping you're doing something to expedite your look up of the blocks - hopfully you can use a hashmap.  I'm more concerned about your 'blocks' - Are you sure that table structure is the best use?  Something strikes me as being 'off'.

Comment: @X-Zero: 10,000 blocks, 200 cars, each of them has its unique copy of an array 129x28 for each block. 200 * 10 000 = 2 000 000 arrays. As for search I have binary search which costs log 10 0000 = O(14) to look up the array to be retrieved and constant time of O(15) to retrieve the exact value in the retrieved array. 

I even considered the RAM capacity in using arrays "at the same time", my pitfall in the code is that I did not consider arrays that I don't use, later on I find out that even those arrays will reside on the RAM too.

Comment: I assumed that an individual terrain block would be the same for every car, therefore allowing it to be shared between them (sharing the reference to the same object).  Cars don't usually cause (immediately noticeable) effects on terrain, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reasonably easy solution is to use the ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream classes to write and read your arrays.

Here is some example code to write an array to disk:

```
    int [][] array = new int [129] [28];
    // fill in your array here
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
    out.writeObject(array);
    out.close();
```

Here is some example code to read a previously saved array from disk:

```
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
    int [] [] inArray = (int [] []) in.readObject();
    in.close();
```

Comment: thanks. but isn't there away to automate the fileName. I mean, I need to name the file which I will save the array in (2 million arrays = 2 million files). So is there away to automate file naming to save each array ?

Comment: Here is one solution. There are 200 cars, each of which travels over 10,000 blocks. So you could set up a separate subdirectory for each car, and store 10,000 files in each subdirectory. So, for example, /carfiles/car99/block250.dat would contain the data for car 99 block 250.

Comment: Continuing the above comment. However, with 2 million arrays, the database suggestion is a good one. Set up a table indexed by car number and block number, with a BLOB (Binaary Large Object) containing the data. You can use my Object Stream code above, in conjunction with ByteArrayOutputStream and ByteArrayInputStream (instead of FileOutputStream and FileInputStream) to write/read the data to/from a byte array, which is stored in the BLOB.